# Filtering of array values and rendering in react UI

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

- I am new to react application
- I am trying to get user input values from drop down box , check box and text boxes
- Followed by validation with array of objects (JSON) values, and rendering the filtered array values in UI
- I have used array.filter() method and conditional rendering for execution
- Also, I am struck with filtering as well as rendering filtered values
- values to be rendered in UI are players name and sports grade
- can you guys help me to solve the issue with your suggestions
- Entire code is available in the stackblitz link:https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-geum6v?file=index.js
- providing the code snippet below:

index.js

```
Players Belonging to same zip code:
     <input type="text" name="zip_code" defaultValue={zip1} onChange={this.handleChange_zip}></input> <br />

      Number of male over certain age: <input type="number" name="age_number" defaultValue= {age1} onChange={this.handleChange_age}></input> <br />

      Students not Belonging from a given state: 
      <select value={state1} onChange={this.handleChange_state}>
        <option value="select">Select</option>
        <option value="CA">CA</option>
        <option value="TX">TX</option>
      </select><br/>

      List of Subjects received grades: <input type="checkbox" name="subjects" value={check} onChange={this.handleChange_sub}></input><br/>

      <button onClick={this.sportsZipSearch.bind(this)}>Submit</button><br />
      {zipValue && <Zip result={result} />}


sportsZipSearch = () => {
    const { zip1, age1, count } = this.state;

    const newArray = students.filter((el) => { return ((el.zip === zip1) && (el.Age <= age1) && (el.sports_state === state1) && check) });
    this.setState({ result: newArray, zipValue: true })
  }
```

zip.js

```
const Zip = (props) => {
  return(
    props.result.map(
      results => 
      <h1 key={results.player_first_name}>{results.player_first_name}</h1>
      /* This is not a perfect key, but given the values at hand */
      )
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be careful when compare string like **(el.Age <= age1)**. You should parse it into int before do the comparision. Change to:

```
parseInt(el.Age) <= parseInt(age1))
```

This compare will make you filter return [empty]. For ex:

```
("15" <= "100")
 -> return false
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your reply...the code is working... but one clarification for future use...if we declare check to false value, on checking the box, could we able to set it to true .... I am trying to render the sports games and with its grades present for games...can you able to provide your suggestion for the sports games iteration under filtered array iteration

Comment: 1. could we able to set it to true >> yes. Change "this.setState({ check: !this.state.check }) inside handleChange_sub function

Comment: Show list Sports:

        {result.length && result[0].Sports_games.map(g => {
          var visibility = (check || g[Object.keys(g)[0]]) ? 'block' : 'none';
          return <div style={{display: visibility}}>{Object.keys(g)[0]} {g[Object.keys(g)[0]]}</div>
          }
        )}

Comment: @nmDat...Thanks for your reply...I understood and worked out well...now I am trying to render the sports games and with its grades present for games...can you able to provide your suggestion for the sports games iteration under filtered array iteration

Comment: @nmDat...Thanks a lot for your reply and suggestion...I'll work out the code and let you know

Comment: Now I am trying to get players with their grades over a certain range of grades, I have used sort function. If possible can you provide your suggestion

Comment: Now I am trying to get players with their grades over a certain range of grades, I have used sort function. If possible can you provide your suggestion... I have updated code in stackblitz and providing link below: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-geum6v?file=index.js